# Constantly freezes the Spring Tool Suite (STS)

Tags: ide, spring-tool-suite

I recently started using the **Spring Tool Suite** (**STS**) for development under Spring Boot.

After not continuing the work after starting **STS** hangs tightly.

Used OS *Linux Mint.*

Tell me how to diagnose the problem of suspense?

Comment: Are you behind any proxy server

Comment: Yeap, there is a proxy server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If STS hangs, I would strongly recommend to:

- capture a thread dump while STS hangs (using jps and jstack)
- file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues and attach the full thread dump
- continue to capture thread dumps and attach them to the issue, sometimes slightly different thread dumps reveal interesting details

The thread dump usually reveals whether there is a thread deadlock under the hood, a network issue, or some other very long running process doing some work.

Comment: is it problem at Eclipse?

Comment: I could maybe answer that if you would capture those thread dumps and attach them to an issue, as recommended above. Otherwise I have no insights into what happens on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue in windows. Encountered when extracted by jar -xvf spring-tool-***.jar.

It has been resolved the way by which the jar is extracted by executing it rather extract directly.
java -jar spring-tool-***.jar